# How do I use String interpolation in a Groovy multiline string?

Tags: groovy, string-interpolation

In Groovy, I have a multiline String, defined with `'''`, in which I need to use interpolation in order to substitute some other variables.

For all my efforts, I can't get it to work -- I assume I need to escape something, which I'm missing.

Here's some sample code:

```
def cretanFood = "Dakos" 
def mexicanFood = "Tacos"
def bestRestaurant = ''' 
${mexicanFood} & ${cretanFood}
'''
print bestRestaurant
```

At the moment, this outputs:

```
${mexicanFood} & ${cretanFood}
```

while I would clearly expect:

```
Tacos & Dakos
```

(Note - I would prefer not to concatenate the strings)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In Groovy, single quotes are used to create immutable Strings, just exactly like Java does with double quotes.

When you use double quotes in Groovy you indicate to the runtime your intention to create a mutable String or Groovy String (GString for short). You may use variable interpolation with mutable Strings, or you can leave it as a regular plain Java String.

This behavior extends to the multi-line String versions; usage of triple single quotes creates an immutable multi-line String whereas triple double quotes creates a Groovy String.

Answer (score 87):

Instead of using `'''` for the `GString` or `multi-line string` use `"""`

```
def cretanFood     = "Dakos"  
def mexicanFood    = "Tacos"
def bestRestaurant = """${mexicanFood} & ${cretanFood}"""
print bestRestaurant​
```

`GString` enclosed in `'''` will not be able to resolve the `placeholder - $`. You can find more details in the [Groovy Documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html) under the heading **String**  and  **String Summary Table** block.

Comment: @gsaslis this is a bery basic groovy multiline string literal

Comment: @gsaslis I have added the reason in the answer.

Comment: @gsaslis did it answer your question?

Answer (score -3):

It may also be a good idea to add the variables out of the triple quotes and just concatenate them with the content. 
Something like this for the cases you have complex content inside the quotes:

```
def bestRestaurant = mexicanFood + """ & """ + cretanFood
```

Since your case is quite simple, this should do it as well:

```
def bestRestaurant = mexicanFood + " & " + cretanFood
```